# Open block blob if exists

Tags: azure, azure-storage

In one scenario I need to load hundreds Azure blobs without being sure they exists.

This code executes 2 round trips to the server – one *HEAD* in `Exists` and one *GET* in `OpenRead`:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = ... ;
Parallel.ForEach( ... => {
    string blobName = ... ;
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    if (blob.Exists()) {
        using (var stream = blob.OpenRead()) {
            ...
        }
     }
});
```

Is possible to…

- open the blob
- without throwing an exception in case it does not exists
- with a single round trip to the server

…?

Comment: Can't you just open it and catch the exception?

Comment: Exceptions are costly in terms of performance and annoying during debugging (in this case).

Comment: Maybe not a solution that works for you, but you could possibly use the [`DebuggerNonUserCode`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738115/can-i-enable-disable-breaking-on-exceptions-programatically) attribute on the code involved to temporarily disable break on exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The best approach would be to not call Exists and catch the exception instead. If you are worried about performance, please note that an exception is thrown from System.Net even with the Exists call. Azure Storage Client Library, however, catches and handles it by returning false to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a one-time hit to get all the blobs in a container then check against that list before retrieving a blob. Here is a method adapted from something I use that returns a HashSet you can use for quick list lookup:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the names of all blobs in a container and optionally containers with a
/// specific prefix.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="container">Name of Container to search</param>
/// <param name="prefix">Further filter where to search in container with a prefix.</param>
/// <returns>HashSet of string that names all blobs in container</returns>
public HashSet<string> GetBlobsInContainer(string container, string prefix)
{
  HashSet<string> theBlobs = new HashSet<string>();

  //GetStorageAcct returns CloudStorageAccount object
  CloudBlobClient blobClient = GetStorageAcct().CreateCloudBlobClient();
  CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container);

  foreach (IListBlobItem item in blobContainer.ListBlobs(prefix, true))
  {
    CloudBlockBlob cbb = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
    theBlobs.Add(cbb.Name);
  }

  return theBlobs;
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but there are hundreds of thousands of blobs. It would take a long time to read them all and the `HashSet<string>` would consume a lot of memory.